# How can I track achievement progress?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I'm preparing to clear Instant Karma tonight, but I want to know how much progress I have made in the achievement.

Is there a way I could track my achievements (like the quests are track-able at the right side)? Or I need to keep waiting until I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, and unlike the achievement system in World of Warcraft, there does not seem to be a way to track achievements *on the main GUI*. You can, of course, continue to track it via the achievement UI, but that's not generally something you want to have open in the middle of a boss fight.

The thing about this particular achievement, though, is that it'll pop up as soon as you achieve it. So until it shows up and you get the toast, know that you've still got skeletal minions to let get killed.

Comment: Another thing that I've noticed, is that the achievement screen doesn't appear to keep itself up to date when you're watching for an achievement that involves multiple kills or whatever, if you check half way through I'm finding it's still sat at 0, even though the achievement is applied at the correct point.

Answer (score 3):

If you click on the achievement from the menu, it will show you your progress.

[image]

You can tell which achievements can be expanded by the `+` icon.

[image]